# Missing assets in IPA when building Xamarin iOS app using msbuild on jenkins

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.ios, msbuild, assets

When building the same app (on Mac VS2019) from the same prepared zip archive with removed bin and obj folders and cleaned solution right before build I get different IPA "archives".

**The one from jenkins** is missing Assets.car and app icons so the app doesn't show home screen icon and splash during loading. During the _CopyResourcesToBundle target that should copy all required assets it gives:

```
Building target "_CopyResourcesToBundle" partially, because some output files are out of date with respect to their input files.
```

Because it runs into partial state it probably doesn't copy all the required files.

When building **on the local** machine with the same VS2019 (8.4.2) for Mac and the same Xcode (11.0) no matter when using IDE or the terminal it gives correct IPA file.

```
Building target "_CopyResourcesToBundle" completely.
...
Output file "bin/iPhone/Release/RssReader.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png" does not exist.
Output file "bin/iPhone/Release/RssReader.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png" does not exist.
Output file "bin/iPhone/Release/RssReader.app/Assets.car" does not exist.
...
          bin/iPhone/Release/RssReader.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
                  LogicalName=AppIcon60x60@2x.png
                  Optimize=false
                  OriginalItemSpec=obj/iPhone/Release/actool/bundle/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
                  OutputPath=bin/iPhone/Release/RssReader.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
          bin/iPhone/Release/RssReader.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
                  LogicalName=AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
                  Optimize=false
                  OriginalItemSpec=obj/iPhone/Release/actool/bundle/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
                  OutputPath=bin/iPhone/Release/RssReader.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
          bin/iPhone/Release/RssReader.app/Assets.car
                  LogicalName=Assets.car
                  Optimize=false
                  OriginalItemSpec=obj/iPhone/Release/actool/bundle/Assets.car
                  OutputPath=bin/iPhone/Release/RssReader.app/Assets.car
```

The above part is obviously not present when building on jenkins.

This looks like several other threads when others were struggling with missing assets and they were clearing some misty Xamarin cache folders, adding and removing assets to the project with rebuild, cleaning and removing bin/obj folders.

This is not the same case as app is always built on the cleared workspace in the tmp location with removed bin and obj folders and cleaned before the build. Adding/removing and moving the location of the resource also doesn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apps cannot be built on symlink locations due to msbuild internal issue.

See: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/7759